# How to optimize this loop?

Tags: java, optimization, for-loop, polygon, voronoi

I am working on a Java program which creates a map using Voronoi. I am using a Java library which generates Voronoi and it is very fast (http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplevoronoi/).

The problem I am facing is that, then, I have to scan every Voronoi edge to know what point is on the left and on the right of the edge to create the polygon which contains each point. It is the class which contains every Voronoi edge:

```
public class GraphEdge
{
    public double x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public int site1;
    public int site2;
}
```

The coordinates `x1, y1, x2, y2` are the edge start and end coordinates and `site1` and `site2` are the indexes of the points which are on the left and on the right of the edge. So, to create the polygon which contains every point I do this:

```
for(int n = 0; n < xValues.length; ++n){
        polygonsList.add(new GPolygon());
        for(GraphEdge mGraphEdge : edgesList){
            if( (xValues[mGraphEdge.site1] == xValues[n] || xValues[mGraphEdge.site2] == xValues[n])
                && (yValues[mGraphEdge.site1] == yValues[n] || yValues[mGraphEdge.site2] == yValues[n]) ){
                polygonsList.get(n).addPoint((int)mGraphEdge.x1, (int)mGraphEdge.y1);
                polygonsList.get(n).addPoint((int)mGraphEdge.x2, (int)mGraphEdge.y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `xValues` and `yValues` are the points coordinates from which I generate the Voronoi diagram and `GPolygon` is a Polygon class I created which extends from `java.awt.Polygon`. These are the times I measured:

- **Voronoi Time:** 283 mS (time to generate Voronoi diagram)
- **Polygon Search Time:** 34589 mS (time to complete the for loop which generates the polygons)
- **Polygon Fill Time:** 390 mS (time to fill the polygons and save to image, which is optional)
- **Points quantity:** 26527 (number of points from which Voronoi is generated)
- **Map Generation Finished**
- **Polygon quantity:** 26527 (number of polygons, one for each point)

As you can see the time is really significant compared to the others, how I can speed up the for loop? What other alternatives I have? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For optimization of working code, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you! Can I post the same in both?

Comment: Try to size the list to the appropriate capacity if you know its final size beforehand.

Comment: Nice that reduce time for about 5000mS! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm, if performance is really bad, it is a good time to think about your choice of algorithm. You have already noted that there is a polygon around each site in the input set - or put differently, the edges that form a polygon have an identical site.

Therefore, something as simple as the following should solve it quite nicely:

```
Map<Integer, List<GraphEdge>> edgesByPolygon = new HashMap<>();
for (GraphEdge edge : edgesList) {
    List<GraphEdge> list = edgesByPolygon.get(edge.site1);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        edgesByPolygon.put(edge.site1, list);
    }
    list.add(edge);

    list = edgesByPolygon.get(edge.site2);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        edgesByPolygon.put(edge.site2, list);
    }
    list.add(edge);
}

for (List<GraphEdge> list : edgesByPolygon.valueSet()) {
    // order the edges by adjacency and construct the polygon instance
    // (a naive algorithm will do, as the average number of edges is small)
}
```

This being a nearly O(n) algorithm (instead of your O(n^2)), I estimate this should be about 1000 times faster.

Comment: It drastically reduced the time! From 30s to just 200mS! Just a question, my map is being draw differently now seems like polygons are not the same. It is the code http://pastebin.com/Yhj8ZcCv. Each List contains the edges for a polygon?

Comment: This is the way to go. Exotic data-structures and micro-optimization are unnecessary here.

Comment: Solved it! My fault! Thank you very much for your help amazing idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, store the new GPolygon into a variable during the for loop rather than add it directly to the list:

```
    for(int n = 0; n < xValues.length; ++n){
        GPolygon polygon = new GPolygon();
        polygonsList.add(polygon);
        for(GraphEdge mGraphEdge : edgesList){
            if( (xValues[mGraphEdge.site1] == xValues[n] || xValues[mGraphEdge.site2] == xValues[n])
                && (yValues[mGraphEdge.site1] == yValues[n] || yValues[mGraphEdge.site2] == yValues[n]) ){
                polygon.addPoint((int)mGraphEdge.x1, (int)mGraphEdge.y1);
                polygon.addPoint((int)mGraphEdge.x2, (int)mGraphEdge.y2);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way you won't have to call get at all.

Comment: This was my first thought, and the only optimization I could think of. Unfortunately, I think @meriton is right; you're going to have to rethink your entire algorithm if performance is that bad.

Comment: True that. I think you should always look at repeated method calls for the getting the same item.

Answer (score 1):

- make sure polygonsList is ArrayList, and not LinkedList.

The lines:

```
polygonsList.get(n).addPoint((int)mGraphEdge.x1, (int)mGraphEdge.y1);
polygonsList.get(n).addPoint
```

can be simpliefied by calling polygonsList.get(n) only once.

Further you can speed up by a factor 100 - 1000 if you have a really high number of edges,

Store your edges in a bucket based [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), either a line quadtree or bounding box quadtree, which I prefer). Then for each search point the quadtree gives you the e.g 16 edges nearby (asuming bucket size = 16). You don't have to iterate of all 10.0000, only for 16.

Comment: The number of edges can greatly vary but I could implement different algorithms based on number of edges, it usually is 10.000 edges or more.

Comment: Updated for use a quadtree as index to the edges

Comment: Really nice I will investigate I don't know much about it, for example, using this http://goo.gl/9Rdo6, longitude and latitude would be me (x,y) coordinates? I will have to pass the data from my ArrayList to the QuadTree.

Comment: The link seems to be using a point quadtree, maybe you can live with that. If you need lines, then you must search for another one. Here in SO there was a link of an Quadtree used for Ant algorithms. The add operation must use either a rectangle or a line (or an object which delivers that)

Comment: Ok I will search that! This link http://goo.gl/tgDDx seems to be what I need using queryByBoundingBox() right? Longitude and Latitude cant take any value or only between 0-180? I mean, can I use them as point coordinates?

Comment: Yes, but normally the voroni diagramm is an alternatve for the quadtree, so these seems strange that you need a quadtree to build up a voroni diagramm.